# Word frequencies from CSV List

Tags: python, list, read.csv

How do you write a list that only counts distinct words from a csv list?

Input: input1.csv
input1.csv = hello,cat,man,hey,dog,boy,Hello,man,cat,woman,dog,Cat,hey,boy

Expected Output: 
hello 1 
cat 2 
man 2 
hey 2 
dog 2 
boy 2 
Hello 1 
woman 1 
Cat 1

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

with open(fname,"r") as f:
     word_counter = collections.Counter(f.read().split(","))
     print(word_counter.most_common())
```

Is probably what I would do ...

Answer (score -2):

First off the files being input can and do vary, so the `input()` is important for different filenames. Secondly we have to make a distinct/unique list so that we have something to work with, establishing the `unique = []` is important to put your list somewhere. Lastly, two loops are needed for this scenario. This can be built differently but, I found this way to be the easiest to write and understand the code.

```
import csv
unique_list = []
with open(input(), 'r') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        for word in row:
            if word not in unique_list:
                unique_list.append(word)
        for unique_word in unique_list:
            count = row.count(unique_word)
            print(unique_word, count)
```

Comment: Did you just make a question and answer yourself? o.O Also please add the missing `import csv` to your answer. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, there's a function to add a question and answer yourself on here, am I not supposed to use that? There are probably quite a few students who are struggling with this question for zyBooks because I'm in college learning course material that is rather dense with little explanation.

Comment: No , no it's perfectly OK. Just surprising and kind of funny :D. Thanks for adding the import. Keep up the good work.